# Aggregate function on DATEDIFF result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in MS SQL server, which has so-called schedule records.

Each schedule is assigned to a user and has a start date. Start date time is the point in time, from which the respective schedule is valid. Prior to that point in time, schedule with an earlier start date is used.

I need to write a query, which determines the ID of the schedule, which was valid on that day.

Let's say there are following records for user X with following start dates:

1. 2008-11-18
2. 2008-12-15
3. 2009-07-02
4. 2009-08-11

On days from 2008-11-18 through 2008-12-14, the valid schedule is 1. On days from 2008-12-15 through 2009-07-01 valid schedule is 2. On days from 2009-07-02 through 2009-08-10 valid schedule is 3. For days 2009-08-11 and later, valid schedule is 4.

`DATEDIFF(day, CAST('X' AS DATETIME), startdate)` calculates the number of days between `X` and `startdate`. For `X=2008-12-20 10:00` and the startimes above it returns following values:

1. -32
2. -5
3. 194
4. 234

In order to calculate start time of a schedule, which is valid at time `X`, I need to find a record, for which `DATEDIFF(day, CAST('X' AS DATETIME), startdate)` returns maximal (closest to zero) negative value.

To do this, I wrote following query

```
SELECT startdate, MAX(DATEDIFF(day, CAST('2008-12-20 10:00' AS DATETIME), startdate))
FROM schedules
WHERE (username = 'username') AND (DATEDIFF(day, CAST('2008-12-20 10:00' AS DATETIME), startdate) < 0)
GROUP BY startdate, DATEDIFF(day, CAST('2008-12-20 10:00' AS DATETIME), startdate)
```

and expected to get **one** row as a result.

But instead, I get 2 rows:

How should I modify the query in order to get one row with maximum negative value of `DATEDIFF(day, CAST('2008-12-20 10:00' AS DATETIME), startdate)` ?

Comment: I believe you shouldn't be grouping by the DATEDIFF function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `top` with `order by` instead:

```
select top 1 s.*
from schedules s
where username = 'username' and CAST('2008-12-20 10:00' AS DATETIME) >= startdate 
order by startdate;
```